# Converting .py to .exe Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to convert my .py to .exe. Unfortunately, I haven't been successful. After pip install py2exe and using build_exe myscript.py I get multiple errors such as the following:

```
\...\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
\...\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
```

I don't understand what this mean. Does it mean there is something wrong with my code? (Weird, cause it runs perfectly). Or is it just py2exe that can't do it??
Thanks a lot

Comment: check pyinstaller

Comment: Hi! Please show complete error log. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about py2exe. I use pyinstaller for creating .exe and it works just fine.

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile filename.py
```

And that's it. Your .exe is in the **dist** folder (dist is created automatically by pyinstaller in the directory where the .py file is).

If you don't want a console (if you have a GUI / writing a background process / have no use for I/O or stderr),

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole filename.py
```

If you want a customized icon,

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole -i iconfile filename.py
```

**Edit:** The *--noconsole* switch is ignored in Linux as far as I know.